# clearing cache for if(file_exists)

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, file-exists

I've some problem regarding file_exists. Please refer to the following code:

```
echo '<a href = "/classifiedads4free-view-all-ads/'.$catid_related.'-'.$cat_name.'/'.$related_ads['0'].'-'.$ad_name.'">';
if(file_exists('/images/ads/'.$related_ads['0'].'a_t.jpg')){
    echo '<img src = "/images/ads/'.$related_ads['0'].'a_t.jpg">';
}
else{
    echo '<img src = "/images/ads/no-pre.png">';
}
    echo '</a>';
```

I couldn't get the condition to work. I mean it will show no images for all if the first image i load is no-pre.png. Even when i navigate the page to another which has a picture, it will still show no-pre.png. I read the docs and understand that the problem might lie where i need to clear the cache for the file_exists, but i don't really know how or where to use it..

Appreciate if anyone can help me out here. Thanks! appreciated.

**Update:** I just found out that it isn't cache as i'm not running multiple file_exists on my script. Only 1. I think the problem lies with the condition. I'm able to get the image to show should i put:

```
   if(!file_exists('/images/ads/'.$related_ads['0'].'a_t.jpg'))//NOTICE the !
```

But now all my file exists returns true and i can't get my no-pre to show.

Then i thought that maybe my url to the file is wrong. But if the image could show when file_exists returns false then shouldn't the image exists..?

Comment: Found the answer. Problem solved. 

file_exists doesn't take in relative paths. 

Therefore, I adjusted my file_exists URL to--> 

        if(file_exists(**$_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}**.'/images/ads/'.$related_ads['0'].'a.jpg')){...code...} and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You need to run [`clearstatcache()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) before running `file_exists()` a second time. Or, just to be safe, call it before `file_exists()` every time.

Comment: I just need to add this code? hmm. seems like the problem doesn't lie in the cache..